# Share Google Calendar to Outlook but without details

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar

I believe there were similar questions ask, but I don't know if the exact one was:

I have a personal Google Calendar, and I want to subscribe to it from my work Outlook 365. It looks fine if I share it with private link, but I don't want to share the details. On the other hand, it does not work in a public mode and link from Google Calendar at all.

Any hints?

Comment: The only way to let people who don't have Google Calendar view your calendar is to make it public. Although we can change the access permissions when making the calendar public, AFAIK, the public link generated cannot be subscribed in Outlook client.

Comment: Currently, the only way for me is to share a private link :/